# Collect different class name which contain 4 element into JSON string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I had some class name which is from r1 to r10. And in one row, I had 4 select option.Which is like:

```
                           <tr class="info" id="alertr1">
                                <td width="30px">1</td>
                                <td width="200px">Likes Authority</td>
                                <td  width="75px;">
                                    <select class="r1" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999;"
                                        onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length"
                                        onmouseout="this.size=1" onchange="this.size=1"  name="qtyL" >  
                                        <option value="0">-</option>
                                        <option value="1" >1</option>
                                        <option value="2" >2</option>
                                        <option value="3" >3</option>
                                        <option value="4" >4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td  width="200px">Enthusiastic</td>
                                <td  width="75px;"> 
                                    <select class="r1" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999;"
                                        onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length"
                                        onmouseout="this.size=1" onchange="this.size=1"  name="qtyO" >  
                                        <option value="0">-</option>
                                        <option value="1" >1</option>
                                        <option value="2" >2</option>
                                        <option value="3" >3</option>
                                        <option value="4" >4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td width="200px">Sensitive Feelings</td>
                                <td width="75px;">
                                    <select class="r1" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999; "
                                        onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length"
                                        onmouseout="this.size=1" onchange="this.size=1"  name="qtyG" >  
                                        <option value="0">-</option>
                                        <option value="1" >1</option>
                                        <option value="2" >2</option>
                                        <option value="3" >3</option>
                                        <option value="4" >4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td  width="180px">Likes Instructions</td>
                                <td width="75px;">
                                    <select class="r1" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999; "
                                        onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length"
                                        onmouseout="this.size=1" onchange="this.size=1"  name="qtyB" >  
                                        <option value="0">-</option>
                                        <option value="1" >1</option>
                                        <option value="2" >2</option>
                                        <option value="3" >3</option>
                                        <option value="4" >4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

I had 10 rows lik this. I want to collect all the element at r1 to r10 into a JSON String and there will be like

```
[
   r1: 4,2,3,1;
   r2: 2,1,3,4;
    .....
    .....
   r10: 2,1,4,3;
]
```

How can I get it using javascript or jquery method through a loop? Because I had use them to put back into my question input if user had entered their answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the object you might be looking for will be like

```
{
   r1: [4,2,3,1],
   r2: [2,1,3,4],
    .....
    .....
   r10: [2,1,4,3]
}
```

since object you mention is invalid, You can use `.each()` to loop over all `select` and them over the options inside it like

```js
$(function(){
 $('#btn').click(function() {
  var res = {};
  console.log($('#tab').find('tr'))
  $('tr').each(function(){
      var tmp = [];
      var cl ;
      $(this).find('select').each(function(){
        cl = $(this).attr('class');
        console.log(cl);
        tmp.push($(this).val());
      })
      
      res[cl] = tmp
  })
  console.log(res);
 })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <div>   <table id="tab"> <tr class="info" id="alertr1">
                                <td width="30px">1</td>
                                <td width="200px">Likes Authority</td>
                                <td  width="75px;">
                                    <select class="r1" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999;"
                                        name="qtyL" >  
                                        <option value="0">-</option>
                                        <option value="1" >1</option>
                                        <option value="2" >2</option>
                                        <option value="3" >3</option>
                                        <option value="4" >4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td  width="200px">Enthusiastic</td>
                                <td  width="75px;"> 
                                    <select class="r1" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999;"
                                        >  
                                        <option value="0">-</option>
                                        <option value="1" >1</option>
                                        <option value="2" >2</option>
                                        <option value="3" >3</option>
                                        <option value="4" >4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td width="200px">Sensitive Feelings</td>
                                <td width="75px;">
                                    <select class="r1" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999; "  name="qtyG" >  
                                        <option value="0">-</option>
                                        <option value="1" >1</option>
                                        <option value="2" >2</option>
                                        <option value="3" >3</option>
                                        <option value="4" >4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td  width="180px">Likes Instructions</td>
                                <td width="75px;">
                                    <select class="r1" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999; "
                                        name="qtyB" >  
                                        <option value="0">-</option>
                                        <option value="1" >1</option>
                                        <option value="2" >2</option>
                                        <option value="3" >3</option>
                                        <option value="4" >4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="info" id="alertr1">
                                <td width="30px">1</td>
                                <td width="200px">Likes Authority</td>
                                <td  width="75px;">
                                    <select class="r2" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999;"  name="qtyL" >  
                                        <option value="0">-</option>
                                        <option value="1" >1</option>
                                        <option value="2" >2</option>
                                        <option value="3" >3</option>
                                        <option value="4" >4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td  width="200px">Enthusiastic</td>
                                <td  width="75px;"> 
                                    <select class="r2" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999;"
                                        name="qtyO" >  
                                        <option value="0">-</option>
                                        <option value="1" >1</option>
                                        <option value="2" >2</option>
                                        <option value="3" >3</option>
                                        <option value="4" >4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td width="200px">Sensitive Feelings</td>
                                <td width="75px;">
                                    <select class="r2" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999; "  name="qtyG" >  
                                        <option value="0">-</option>
                                        <option value="1" >1</option>
                                        <option value="2" >2</option>
                                        <option value="3" >3</option>
                                        <option value="4" >4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td  width="180px">Likes Instructions</td>
                                <td width="75px;">
                                    <select class="r2" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999; "  name="qtyB" >  
                                        <option value="0">-</option>
                                        <option value="1" >1</option>
                                        <option value="2" >2</option>
                                        <option value="3" >3</option>
                                        <option value="4" >4</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr></table>
                            </div>
   <button id="btn">click</button>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you, but may I know why when I press a submit button it show me the log, but is not the value what I had select? It still 1,2,3,4 accordingly?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to only selected value in the object on submit

Comment: yes, what I want is like , for example if I select 2,3,1,4 in each column of r1 and so on until r10, and there will a button when I click it, the result will update to r1: [2,3,1,4] r2:[....what i selected accordingly....] something like this.

Comment: Okay, so each row has the different class and you have 10 such rows, now I understand. Will change the soltution

Comment: Thanks and sorry for misunderstanding you.

Comment: Updated the answer for your need

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I want :D

Comment: I'm sorry, so if I want to store the value using `localStorage` I just use JSON.stringify(res) ??

Comment: Where I should put it?

Comment: Add it just after the console.log(res);

Comment: it show me the error which is **Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.**

Comment: I think I know the problem already, btw another question is how can I call the value that is selected already to specific row and column if I had leave the page then I go back to the page again and use it back the value that I had store?

Comment: fetch it from the localstorage, suppose you saved it like `localStorage.setItem('result', JSON.stringify(res))` then fetch it like `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('result'))`

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't know how to assign them into specific row and column. Is using each loop?

Comment: You can ask a separate question fir that, I will need to think of the solution too

Answer (score 1):

Cant see if this is in a form? You want to collect the user selected data and store it into a JSON object?

Or you want to change form elements depending on different choices in select options?
//
You can go through your select fields maybe like:

```
$.each( $('select:selected'), function() {
values[] = this.val();
}
```

or like this

```
$.each($("[name='r1']"), function() {
values[] = this.val();
});
```

Now you have an array with selected values from select fields. Put it in an object:

```
var storedValues = {
    "r1" : values
 };
```

so something like this should work:

```
$.each($("[name='r1']"), function() {
values[] = this.val();
});
storedValues.r1 = values;
```

and so on so on up to r10. Then you can just use:

```
myValues = JSON.stringify(storedValues);
```

which leaves you with all the data stored something like :

```
{"r1":["1","5","4","3"],"r2":["2","2","1","5"]} .....etc.
```

I believe that answers your question. I suggest you lose all those onclick, onmouseover, etc. event and put all that functionality in a separate JS file.
Fastest and easiest if you hang on to JQuery.

Here is a link to some good stuff about forms:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: Thanks, because of I had 10 row, so I wonder if there are another way to loop it instead of repeating the function.

Comment: I tested it. It works. Every time it passes through :selected it stores its value into values[]. So you get an array like [1,4,6,3]. That is for every 4 select elements (.r1,.r2,.r3....). Going through them all in one function I didn't succedd,